# How to verify execution of a final method with Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am trying to verify the execution of a final method with Mockito like:

```
Mockito.verify(this.productClassQualifierQueryFactory).setEntityManager(this.em);
```

With this I am getting the below error:

```
Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

From the error I understand that we cannot verify final or private methods with Mockito.

But is there other way of doing it with Mockito or PowerMock?

Comment: Isn't the error clear enough?

Comment: I understood the error and that I have mentioned in the question itself. I am asking if there is any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your tests with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and prepare classes having final and static method with `@PrepareForTest(ClassName.class)`

Comment: Thanks @Halayem. It worked fine. But is there any way to do it with Mockito only?

Comment: Mockito does not support mocking final and static methods